# onclick function change video

Tags: javascript

im quite a bigginer in js and do not understand, why the following code isnt working.

JS - Code:

```
function videoUrl(moin)
{
    document.getElementById("video_item").src = moin;
}
```

HTML - Code:

```
<section id="second">

                <div id="slide">

                    <div id="videos">

                        <video class="video_item" src="videos\Hair - 43633.mp4" autoplay muted loop> </video>
                        <!-- <video class="video_item" src="videos\Road - 81676.mp4" autoplay muted loop> </video>
                        <video class="video_item" src="videos\Skyscrapers - 80724.mp4" autoplay muted loop> </video>
                        <video class="video_item" src="videos\Tunnel - 84938.mp4" autoplay muted loop> </video> -->

                    </div>
                    
                    <ul id="video_navigation">

                        <li> <img src="image\moon-6616172_1920.jpg" alt="moon" class="img_video_nav" onclick="videoUrl('Hair - 43633.mp4')"> </li> 
                        <li> <img src="image\background-313415.jpg" alt="moon" class="img_video_nav" onclick="videoUrl('Road - 81676.mp4')"> </li> 
                        <li> <img src="image\blue-5457731_1920.jpg" alt="moon" class="img_video_nav" onclick="videoUrl('Skyscrapers - 80724.mp4')"> </li> 
                        <li> <img src="image\adventure-5077752_1920.jpg" alt="moon" class="img_video_nav" onclick="videoUrl('Tunnel - 84938.mp4')"> </li> 

                    </ul>

                </div>
                
            </section>
```

Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOKbF.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to change src of all vides with `class="video_item"`?

Comment: i want to change the video which is played in the "videos" div to another one int the "videos" div when i press a picture ( like a thumbnail )

Comment: Instead of `document.getElementById("video_item").src = moin;`  use `document.querySelector(".video_item").src = moin;`

Comment: this just lets the video go away completly

Comment: So you want to play video whose thumbnail is clicked?

Comment: At first which video is played? First thumbnail video?

Comment: yes right, so the first video which is played is the "Hair - 43633.mp4" and this should be the thumbnail with the bottle on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');

function videoUrl(url){
    video.pause();
    const source = video.querySelector("source");
    source.setAttribute('src', url); 
    video.load();
    video.play();
}
```

```html
<div id="videos">
    <video class="video_item" id="video" width="320" height="240" autoplay muted loop controls>
        <source src="https://imdb-video.media-imdb.com/vi1229043737/1434659607842-pgv4ql-1525282650955.mp4?Expires=1633358484&Signature=oU3FcWKNZz2uAI~mBFOmBvhQ3EAXzZEfWUzRKGCOvFMoVddy5NTm5Px0bUNKhohSRvtS5veQ02lg44jUd5I9FYyHZpEbTIKtBI8~rklmoi6yAV1jprzHRQiazRr1Cx2cfPoT7-EWJ3Psxy6HYfZZFT8StX~udIEw0cIQofLwGyUzRL-OQc-RPWjkY0FSB~9cJbM0hrE-RNrZUwDyZgRk-5vk-t4xHpZJiQ5QR8Hjw1Izg9U0RYdkksnhucaZlX~OF7v-xPuK0y0oObn1TtOSnO4wwxWW8eh7hSj5cu6v8snWRW5IQb4F~0EMwtHqF3X1RoDhe697J8Au7wlLsv1XlA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFLZBVQZ24NQH3KA">
    </video>
    
        <!--<video class="video_item" src="videos\Hair - 43633.mp4" autoplay muted loop> </video>-->
</div>
    
<ul id="video_navigation">
    <li> <img src="image\moon-6616172_1920.jpg" alt="moon" class="img_video_nav" onclick="videoUrl('https://imdb-video.media-imdb.com/vi1229043737/1434659607842-pgv4ql-1525282650955.mp4?Expires=1633358484&Signature=oU3FcWKNZz2uAI~mBFOmBvhQ3EAXzZEfWUzRKGCOvFMoVddy5NTm5Px0bUNKhohSRvtS5veQ02lg44jUd5I9FYyHZpEbTIKtBI8~rklmoi6yAV1jprzHRQiazRr1Cx2cfPoT7-EWJ3Psxy6HYfZZFT8StX~udIEw0cIQofLwGyUzRL-OQc-RPWjkY0FSB~9cJbM0hrE-RNrZUwDyZgRk-5vk-t4xHpZJiQ5QR8Hjw1Izg9U0RYdkksnhucaZlX~OF7v-xPuK0y0oObn1TtOSnO4wwxWW8eh7hSj5cu6v8snWRW5IQb4F~0EMwtHqF3X1RoDhe697J8Au7wlLsv1XlA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFLZBVQZ24NQH3KA')"> </li> 
    <li> <img src="image\background-313415.jpg" alt="moon" class="img_video_nav" onclick="videoUrl('https://imdb-video.media-imdb.com/vi4210998297/1434659607842-pgv4ql-1557169076640.mp4?Expires=1633358564&Signature=kdOmIWItw1tSY3BTzVNLATmRS1RFyf1J-5HjJZPesSrxk50c02E4Mefb8z6B76i7AGsiNRmbXw5mZBn6qv6KY~Ag15voKEVK~6mxmM9N9EV52YXYzYosqK2YfuSmHE-QiwyQt3IeQ41jC1mSFXlh8uqXOXmBMx1vaRLWHU1K2toJmE1vXSycbwwtm6pARUdVnUY5rQcT0vthpdEMvZRQn~58meyUv8Ml8GWNvKZ91~N2Ivu-0czpMJFm4VL71beSXpP6N4b9fVE~1Jp6yslWPFU99o0tVb0GIb8nW6VEGo~xVC300BxDi-EkyJqVrxTq75hzMX8aOq~jM-m-A-WCGg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFLZBVQZ24NQH3KA')"> </li> 
    <li> <img src="image\blue-5457731_1920.jpg" alt="moon" class="img_video_nav" onclick="videoUrl('https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/movie.mp4')"> </li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: unfortunately this isnt functioning either

Comment: can you share your code somewhere?

Comment: @helloworld Check updated answer. You can run the above script.

Comment: Hi @navanath thank you for your help. It still not works for some reason but i understood  it now